# OpenCV 3.1.0: Accessing single elements from a UMat

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.1

I'm currently transferring a program in OpenCV 2.4.9 over to OpenCV 3.1.0, however I've been having trouble changing from `Mat`s to `UMat`s. I use `Mat`s to store pictures that I need to access single binary pixel values from. In 2.4.9 I did it like so:

```
Mat test_mat;
test_mat.at<uchar>(row,column);
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a way to do the same sort of thing with the `UMat`s OpenCV 3.1.0 provides through my research. Does anyone have any ideas? Apologies if this is a really trivial thing.

Comment: If anyone is wondering why I'm doing this, I need the processing speed-boost that 3.1.0 provides over 2.4.9

Comment: If my answer worked for you, [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If it didn't, add a comment asking for clarification or corrections if needed (I guess you can only comment on your own question as per your current reputation, but no worries I will read it).

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
UMat test_umat;
test_umat.getMat(ACCESS_READ).at<uchar>(row, column);
```

Different access flags are:

- ACCESS_READ
- ACCESS_WRITE
- ACCESS_RW
- ACCESS_FAST

Comment: This command casts to cv::Mat() which loses the performance of UMat. So the question should be, is there a similar function .at() on UMat class? It will be very helpful for me.

Comment: you are right, opencv Internally uses .getMat(Access) to access to especific elements from the functions.